# Using JSON with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-maps

I'm new to using APIs and this is what I am trying to accomplish, but I really have no idea on how to go about it. I have an `OpenCaching` developer key and I can access a URL like:

```
test.opencaching.com/api/geocache?center=38.642,-94.754&limit=2&Authorization=DevKey
```

which would return information on the 2 closest geocaches from coordinates `38.642, -94.754`. The URL returns something along the lines of...

```
[{"name":"John Brown Hill","location":{"lat":38.55345,"lon":-94.91825}},{"name":"Ensor Farm","location":{"lat":38.7956167,"lon":-94.8052667}}]
```

I am trying to use this data to map it using Google Maps API, but I don't understand how I would save the data to a JavaScript object. If I hard coded the data in I know how to use it, but I don't know how to dynamically get it from this URL.

Comment: These resources should help you out, please give them a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use jQuery and do something like this:

```
$.getJSON("the_url_to_data", function(data) {
    var map = new.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("my_map"),{
    ...map params...
    };

    var cache = data.list.Caches // depending on how your JSON is actually returned.

    $.each(cache, function(i, cache) {
        var name = cache.name; // 
        var posi = new google.maps.LatLng(cache.lat, cache.lon);
        ...etc...
    }
};
```

`$.getJSON` returns a a JSON object and then the anonymous function takes it as a parameter.

The example of  `var cache = data.list.Caches`  is based on having nested JSON.

There's a good page of examples here from Adobe actually.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html#Example4

So using your example data. You can see that "location" is actually another nested JSON object. You'd access it by `data.location`. It just makes it easier to iterate over if you loop over your object and put them in a list. Then access those smaller objects using the same path 'dot' format. e.g. loop over your example code putting all the `data.location` objects into a variable called `coords` (for example) and then access the lats & lons by `coords.lat` & `coords.lon`.

```
[{"name":"John Brown Hill","location":{"lat":38.55345,"lon":-94.91825}},{"name":"Ensor Farm","location":{"lat":38.7956167,"lon":-94.8052667}}]
```

Comment: Do you know where I could find some examples of this? I'm having a hard time understanding it :/

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to see what I can figure out from that.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to how 'var cache = data.list.Caches' can vary depending how the JSON is returned?

Comment: Thanks! This helped greatly. I also discovered I had to add "&callback=?" onto the end of the URL to request a JSONP response due to cross-domain restrictions.